# How to delete all characters and lines between two XML tags

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I have an XML file which I want to modify with Notepad++. All I want is to delete all characters and lines (simply everything) between two "properties" tags.

```
<properties>
<property>
  <propertyName>controlPanelDemoURL</propertyName>
  <propertyValues>
    <propertyValue>http://domain.com</propertyValue>
  </propertyValues>
</property>
</properties>
```

It should look like this:

```
<properties>
</properties>
```

What regular expresion (or Notepad++ extended search) should I use?

I've tried `<properties>.*</properties>`but it works only when everything is located in one line.

---

Thanks l'L'l. Now I realized I have other problem. Tag `<properties></properties>` is a part  of main `<template></template>` tag. There is a lot "template" items in this xml file. After using `<properties>.*</properties>` and replacing with dot matches new line, I'm deleting all of code, started from first  until last  and every other tag between.

Simplfied XML file structure look like this:

```
<templates>
<template id="1">
  <id></id>
  <state></state>
  <price></price>
  <type_name></type_name>
  <live_preview_url></live_preview_url>
  <properties>
  <property>
      <propertyName></propertyName>
      <propertyValues>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
      </propertyValues>
    </property>
  </properties>
 </template>
 <template id ="2">
  <id></id>
  <state></state>
  <price></price>
  <type_name></type_name>
  <live_preview_url></live_preview_url>
  <properties>
  <property>
      <propertyName></propertyName>
      <propertyValues>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
      </propertyValues>
    </property>
  </properties>
 </template>
</templates>
```

Comment: You need to select `dot matches newline` - http://superuser.com/a/481281

Comment: This one will work be very wary of regex and markup though <Properties><![CDATA[This tag ends with a </Properties>/r/n]]></Properties>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find

```
<properties>.*?</properties>
```

And replace with

```
<properties></properties>
```

Use `Regular expressions` and `. matches a newline`